# How to fix videos that can be played although they are corrupted

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec

My case is, I did to convert a video with a mediacodec lib, then I sent the converted file to another device. Before I sent to another device, that file could run normally. But when file is received, that file is corrupted but still can be played and show a dialog like "Can't properly play this file due to an unexpected error has occured".

This is an error log:

```
05-26 10:10:53.522 299-12376/? E/ACodec: [OMX.Intel.aac.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
05-26 10:10:53.522 299-12376/? E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
05-26 10:10:53.522 299-12376/? E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 6
05-26 10:10:53.522 299-12375/? E/NuPlayerDecoder: Failed to dequeue input buffer for OMX.Intel.aac.decoder (err=-38)
05-26 10:10:53.523 299-12365/? E/NuPlayer: received error(0xffffffda) from audio decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
05-26 10:10:53.523 2608-14507/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
05-26 10:10:53.523 2608-2608/? E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
05-26 10:10:53.523 2608-2608/? D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38
05-26 10:10:53.523 2608-2608/? D/MoviePlayerForL: Gallery MoviePlayer Receive error
05-26 10:10:53.523 299-12375/? E/NuPlayerDecoder: failed to flush OMX.Intel.aac.decoder (err=-38)
05-26 10:10:53.523 299-12365/? E/NuPlayer: received error(0xffffffda) from audio decoder, flushing(2), now shutting down
05-26 10:10:53.526 2608-29677/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
05-26 10:10:53.527 299-12376/? E/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: 1
05-26 10:10:53.527 299-12376/? E/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: 2
05-26 10:10:53.527 299-12376/? E/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: 3
```

Now my question is, what makes that file is broken and how to fix it?